# How to show messages from server side to dialog in Primefaces

Tags: jsf, primefaces

Good morning, I'm doing a method  that verify if exist a brand in the database and show a message that the brand is just present, i would like to access to the dialog "manageBrand" and put this message inside it whitout exit from the dialog.
It's possible do that in Primefaces?

```
<p:dialog id ="manageBrand" header="Brand Details" showEffect="fade" modal="true"
                  widgetVar="manageBrandDialog" responsive="true">
                  <p:growl id="messaggi" showDetail="true"/>
            <p:panelGrid id="manage-product-content" class="ui-fluid" columns="2">
                
                   <p:outputPanel rendered="#{not empty marcaController.selected}">
                    <div class="p-field">
                        <p:outputLabel for="name">Name</p:outputLabel>
                        
                        <p:inputText id="name" value="#{marcaController.selected.nome}" required="true"/>
                    </div>
                   
                    </p:outputPanel>  
                  
            </p:panelGrid>

            <f:facet name="footer">
                <p:commandButton value="Save" icon="pi pi-check" action="#{marcaController.creaMarca()}"
                                 update="manage-brand-content" process="manage-brand-content @this"/>
                <p:commandButton value="Cancel" icon="pi pi-times" onclick="PF('manageBrandDialog').hide()"
                                 class="ui-button-secondary"/>
            </f:facet>
        </p:dialog>
```

```
public void creaMarca() {
        //m = selectedbrand
       if(m.getIdmarca()==null) {
           List<Marca> list = marcaDao.ricercaMarcaByNome(m.getNome());//find if exixt a brand with selected name
           if(list.isEmpty()||list==null) {
               try {
                marcaDao.create(m);
                FacesMessage m = new FacesMessage
                        (FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, "Creazione andata a buon fine"
                                ,"OK");
                FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage("Success", m);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                FacesMessage m = new FacesMessage
                        (FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, e.getMessage()
                                ,"KO");
                FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage("Error", m);
                
                
            } 
               PrimeFaces.current().executeScript("PF('manageBrand').hide()");
                PrimeFaces.current().ajax().update("form:messages", "form:datatable-brands");
           }
           else {
               
               FacesMessage m = new FacesMessage
                        (FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, "Brand  exist "
                                ,"OK");
               
               PrimeFacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, m);
               PrimeFaces.current().ajax().update(":messaggi","form:manageBrand");
               //PrimeFaces.current().dialog().showMessageDynamic(m);
               
           }
            
       }
```

Comment: If you update all your dialog it will be closed, try removing that and adding `<p:autoUpdate/>` within your growl (for older PF version use the property `autoUpdate="true"`), or move the growl in a container and update only that. As a last way, not recommended, keep your code and add a PF('manageBrandDialog').show(), after the update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updating a dialog by its id, in your case, will close it. To avoid that, you should update only the desired element, or its container, or remove that update, and set the growl to autoUpdate. Another way should be setting your message, server-side, to a specific id.